# Call controller function on button clik isn't working

Tags: codeigniter

I want to call controller function named as CreateData() on submit button click,but its not working.

here is my code.

```
<form method="post" >
<input type="submit"  value="CREATE" name="btncreate" id="btncreate" />        
</form> 

function CreateData(){    
   if($this->input->post('btncreate'))
      $this->load->view('demo');
}
```

Comment: "but its not working" is the most useless statement you can ever give when seeking support. What doesn't work? The button does not fire the submit action? The page goes to a 404? The page throws an error? You server randomly explodes when you load it? You have to define an error before we have any chance of helping you solve it.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot 'action' attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="your_controller/CreateData" >
<input type="submit"  value="CREATE" name="btncreate" id="btncreate" />        
</form> 

function CreateData(){
   $this->load->view('demo');
}
```

Comment: i wish stackoverflow would let me just say "LOL" and be done w/ it.